# Is it possbile to implement the index operator '[]' with generic capability

Tags: c#, generics, indexing, brackets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why it is not posible to define generic indexers in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494827/why-it-is-not-posible-to-define-generic-indexers-in-net)
>   [how to write a function to take any object with an index operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544227/how-to-write-a-function-to-take-any-object-with-an-index-operator)

I've never seen any usage like that. But I just wonder if it is possible to make an implementation like bleow. I know that it's not working. But I mean a similar usage if exist.

```
public T this<T>[T param]
{
    get 
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick search would answer your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494827 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043028/

Comment: It is possible using an interface `public interface IIndexable<I,T> { T this[I index] { get; set; } }` and adding this to your method/class `where T : class, IEnumerableExtensions.IIndexable<string, T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, generic properties, and indexers (*a* property), aren't possible.